# Warning Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252). 8-bit characters might not work correctly in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, windows

Whenever I access psql, I get the following message:

```
psql (9.6.2)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
     8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
     page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I tried command

```
cmd.exe /c chcp 1252
```

before running runpsql.bat file in command line. And there, it runs fine without the error. But accessing psql again after closing command prompt, throws the same warning. How do I solve this warning within SQL Shell?

I am using windows 10 OS.

**Edit:**

This is what I did:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Sarthak Joshi>E:

E:\>cd PostgreSQL

E:\PostgreSQL>cd scripts

E:\PostgreSQL\scripts>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

E:\PostgreSQL\scripts>runpsql.bat
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

But after exiting from cmd, and firing up shell like this:

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.6.2)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

It still throws the same warning...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `cmd.exe /c chcp 1252` in the batch file, you start a **new** command line, change the codepage for that and then that command line is immediately terminated, but the one that runs `psql` has not bee changed.

Just put:

```
chcp 1252
```

(without calling `cmd.exe`) into the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Powershell as well.

```
chcp 1252

$connstr = -join ("postgresql://", $dbUser, ":", $dbPW, "@", $connStringEndPoint, ":5432/db")

.\psql $connstr --filename="TestConn.sql"
```

Comment: Nice solution to this issue!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, running chcp in a new command line interpreter context does not work. Here's how I wrapped my Windows PostgreSQL client start in a batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
chcp 1252
if [%1]==[] (set psqlhost=localhost) else (set psqlhost=%1)
if [%2]==[] (set psqluser=postgres) else (set psqluser=%2)
if [%3]==[] (set psqldbase=postgres) else (set psqldbase=%3)
if [%4]==[] (set psqlport=5432) else (set psqlport=%4)

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\psql.exe" -h %psqlhost% -U %psqluser% -d %psqldbase% -p %psqlport%
endlocal
```

Create this batch script as e.g. `%APPDATA%\psql.bat`.  Make sure you have the correct path to `psql.exe`, I'm using version 11 in Windows 10 (x64).

Passwords can be stored in `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` as described in [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-pgpass.html).

Script can be executed by issuing `%appdata%\psql` on the command line or as I like to use it, in Windows Terminal profile:

[image: PostgreSQL command line client running in Windows Terminal]